# Possible to use internal LSI controllers in HP hosts?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware, hp, lsi

Right now I have a HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 with two SATA disks in the disk bays. These are the OS disks. I choose SATA disks to bypass the internal raid controller, so ZFS could do the raid.

I now need a 2U host, and would like to use SAS disks instead of SATA disks for the OS. Looking at pictures of opened HP hosts, I can only see one SATA cable going to the mainboard, where I was hoping to see one from each disk bay, as it then would be more likely that I can completely bypass the onboard controller.

So my question is

Can I just buy a LSI SAS 9207-8i, and connect the disk bays directly to that controller? Or do I need a specific HP host to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install an [LSI PCIe controller](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwhite/albums/72157625918734321) in an HP server.

[image]

You disconnect the internal SAS cables from the motherboard ports and connect them to the add-in HBA(s).

Comment: Great. Do you know if each disk bay have their own SATA cable, or should I only expect to find one SATA cable from all the disk bays?

Comment: Each group of 4 disks on the backplane has a SAS SFF 8087 port. So for 4 disks, you would use one connector. For up to 8 disks, you would use 2 connectors. The "8i" in 9207-8i means it accommodates 8 disks using two 4-lane ports.